On running multiple mysql slaves using same data directory
In our production system, we have 8 slave databases of 17tb size each. data is being replicated from common master in real time to these slaves .
now my question is can i

run mysql slave on a clustered file system which i will host on aws multi attach io2. (from my knowledge i think this can be done, which clustered file system to choose i am not sure)
now since 1 slave is already replicating from master to clustered file system. can i run another slave reading data from same data directories as that of first slave (via another server having same data directory on clustered file system )


What i am intending to do?
trying to create aurora mysql like functionality in lesser cost. I just need multiple slaves to share the storage and compute can get scaled easily.
mysql version 8
clustered fs - un decided
disk - aws ebs io2

How do you plan to keep ACIDity on the shared storage? How does your r/o slave will know that replication slave start ON DELETE CASCADE just in the middle of r/o query?

My schema is very simple lacking any cascade or trigger. Also that will be temporary inconsistency which I can live with.

You can easily start two instances of mysql on the same host - but with different configs - port, basedir, tmpdir and such - and check whether it is work at all. I had never tried such setup cause I am aware of possible consequencies. But if it is not so critical for you you can try it.

thanks @Kondybas I'll try it out and share my findings. : )


I'll have to start non replicating MySQL with configurations from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/innodb-read-only-instance.html
One thing that I have to manage is that replicating slave is writing in the buffer pool. So there is going to be some data which has been replicated in replicating slave's memory but not applied on disk. So it would be available to replicating slave but available via non replicating slave.

To solve this, we can flush the buffer pool for every transaction. but this would lead to I/O operations increasing on the disk.
